# Replace a word only if it's not preceded by a certain character(s)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I like to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript where the string does not start with `<` or `/`.  I was able to match the word but I want to replace the word only, not the preceding characters.

```
var hitName1 = "body";

var testHtmlStr = "This is a test string with <body> html tag and with regular body string and another <body> html string and with no flexbody and with /body as in a url string";

var re5 = new RegExp('[^<\/]' + hitName1 , 'gi');

console.log(re5);

var testResult5 = testHtmlStr.match(re5);

console.log(testResult5);
```

I get the result `[" body", "xbody"]`

If I use `replace()` instead of `match()` I will replace " body" and "xbody" with replace string. But I would like to replace only "body" with replace string. How to do that?

**More explanation:**

**use of replace:**

```
var testResult5 = testHtmlStr.replace(re5, "HELLO");

console.log(testResult5);
```

The resulting string after replacement:

```
"This is a test string with <body> html tag and with regularHELLO string and another <body> html string and with no fleHELLO and with /body as in a url string"
```

The replace function replaced `body` with `HELLO`, but I want to replace `body` (with nospace infront). Also the `xbody` replaced with `HELLO`, but I want to replace only `body` not `xbody`.

Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do it is defining a capturing group around the preceding character:

```
var hitName1='body';
var testHtmlStr = "This is a test string with <body> html tag and with regular body string and another <body> html string and with no flexbody and with /body as in a url string";
var re5 = new RegExp('([^<\/]|^)' + hitName1, 'gi');

alert(testHtmlStr.replace(re5, '$1'));
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QSyxj/1/)

So if you want to replace your string with `fos` for example, you can write `$1fos`.

**UPDATE**: Following @yankee's comment I've changed the regex: added `|^` to make it work when `testHtmlStr` starts with `hitName1` or is equal to it.

Comment: This will not work if testHtmlStr = hitName1; Check for beginning of string `([^<\/]|\A)` as well

Comment: I modified                                alert(testHtmlStr.replace(re5, '$1'+replaceStr));                  I got the following result                                     "This is a test string with <body> html tag and with regular HELLO string and another <body> html string and with no flexHELLO and with /body as in a url string"

Answer (score 0):

well i couldn't understand what you want to do exactly but i think you are trying to replace some tags from a string that contains tags and other textNodes

However, i think if you use "for" loop to verify which tags should be replace and which tags shouldn't, you will be able to do what you need.

```
for(result in testResult5)
{
    if(result!="body") {// do what you want}
}
```